# page load without refresh jquery

Tags: jquery, function, load, refresh

I wonder, which is the best way how to load whole page or part of it without refreshing.
I am using this method:

```
$(".updated").load("index.php .updated");
```

That's how I refresh table with class .updated. But after some re-loads part of my other jQuery functions work not properly or don't work at all.

Which method do you use? And what you could advise to me?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give more detail on what is not working?

Comment: for example AddClass function which should change color of <tr> after pressing a button. Before first .load i works perfectly, after -  it add a class but you need to manually refresh (F5) the page.

Comment: JudJin , thought that might be the case. Looks like Apache Fan has your answer down there.

Comment: I can't understand it fully. I understand how to add a content (for example one more table row) without refreshing, but not how to update content of specific row.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I'm not fully understanding your problem... I've started up two jsbins for you. If you could modify them to what you are seeing that would help. I have them setup now to do what I 'think' you're looking for but again, I'm not certain of that... This link has the functioning JS: http://jsbin.com/urihev/1/edit  this link is just for an updated table: http://jsbin.com/uyizok/2/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If parts of your page are being reloaded using AJAX calls you should use the following functions -

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

This will ensure that an handler is attached to all elements that match the selector now or in the future.

**Example -**

```
  $("body").delegate("p", "click", function(){
      $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
  });
```

**Further Reference -**

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/on/